# Values are not passing from Tableview to collectionview

Tags: ipad, uicollectionview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am passing values from table view to collection view controller using SwReveal view controller. when I click a cell in collection view I stored the collection view cell's index path. But when I select a table and pass a value to the index path collection view. The cell not displaying the value. It is null... here is my code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    text=seltext;
    NSLog(@"text %@",text);

 **// HERE I AM GETTING VALUES FROM TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER**

    self.displayindex=Viewindex;
    NSLog(@"self dispaly %@",Viewindex);

  **// HERE I AM GETTING INDEX PATH OF SELECTED COLLECTION CELL**

    Cell *cells = (Cell *)[collectionData cellForItemAtIndexPath: self.displayindex];
    cells.subjectLabel.text=@"djhfkjdshfjkhd";
    cells.cellView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    NSLog(@"cell is %@",cells);
    NSLog(@"text %@",text);

**// CELL IS NULL HERE AND NOTHING IS DISPLAYING EVEN IF I PASS THE CELL FRO ITEM INDEXPATH**

        }
```